# Exception in generated editor: Xtext bug or error in grammar?

Tags: eclipse, parsing, xtext

After moving to Xtext 2.4.2 and Eclipse Kepler, a problem appeared in the editor of our DSL. Everything was perfectly working before (Xtext 2.3.x, Juno).

Our DSL editor throws a ClassCastException when we edit an initialization list:
`[1,2,3]`
[image: Xtext Error Pop-up]

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Create a new "Xtext State-Machine Example" project
2. Edit the grammar with the one below
3. Delete the package org.eclipse.xtext.example.fowlerdsl.generator (it will be regenerated at 4.)
4. Run the org.eclipse.xtext.example.fowlerdsl.GenerateStatemachine.mwe2 workflow
5. Run the eclipse application
6. Create a new file (example.statemachine) in an empty project and copy the folowing content

**Grammar:**

```xtext
grammar org.eclipse.xtext.example.fowlerdsl.Statemachine
    with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals
generate statemachine "http://www.eclipse.org/xtext/example/fowlerdsl/Statemachine"

Statemachine : {Statemachine}
    (vars += VarDeclWithOptionalInit)*
;
VarDeclWithOptionalInit returns Variable:
    VarDecl ('=' value=AstExpression)?
;
VarDecl returns Variable:
    'var' name = ID
;
AstExpression:
      ExpressionList
    | {AstExpression} INT
;
ExpressionList:
    '[' expressions+=AstExpression (',' expressions+=AstExpression)* ']'
;
```

**Content of example.statemachine**

```js
//Adding space between chars inside [] cause Exception
var example1 = [1, 2, 3]

//Doing the same in [10, 20] or [30, 40] is Ok, but modifying
//the top-level list cause the Exception
var example2 = [[10, 20], 0, [30, 40], 1, 2]
```

I think the content of the example file is correct. But when I edit lists with new values, or when I add spaces around commas or values, the editor pop-up an error with a ClassCastException from the XtextReconcilierJob.

Do you think my grammar has something wrong, or is it a bug from Xtext side ?

**Additional information**

I fight against this for some days, and I collected some interesting information:

- In the example, editor throws only when editing elements from the top-level list, not from inner ones (see example2 variable)
- In my tests, sometimes a `NullPointerException` was throwed earlier in the call stack.

  - I suspect the method `PartialParsingHelper.reparse(IParser parser, IParseResult prev, ReplaceRegion cr)` to have a strange behavior
  - This method found the parent of the current modified element in the model, to call eSet() on this with the new value. But in our case, it try to call `Statemachine.eSet()` instead of `Variable.eSet()`
  - The `ClassCastException` comes from an equal feature id:

    - `StateMachine.vars` has a feature id == 0
    - `Variable.value` has a feature id == 0
    - But the 2 features have not the same type
  - If I add some feature BEFORE value in `Variable`, the Exception thrown (earlier) is a `NullPointerException`, because `Variable.value` has a feature id == 2 or 3 when `StateMachine` has only 2 features (0 and 1)

**StackTrace of the error:**

```
Thread [Worker-2] (Suspended (exception ClassCastException))
    StatemachineImpl.eSet(int, Object) line: 128
    StatemachineImpl(BasicEObjectImpl).eSet(EStructuralFeature, Object) line: 1071
    PartialParsingHelper.reparse(IParser, IParseResult, ReplaceRegion) line: 161
    StatemachineParser(AbstractAntlrParser).doReparse(IParseResult, ReplaceRegion) line: 136
    StatemachineParser(AbstractParser).reparse(IParseResult, ReplaceRegion) line: 48
    LazyLinkingResource(XtextResource).update(int, int, String) line: 220
    XtextDocumentReconcileStrategy.doReconcile(IRegion) line: 125
    XtextDocumentReconcileStrategy.reconcile(IRegion) line: 55
    XtextReconciler.doRun(XtextResource, IProgressMonitor) line: 329
    XtextReconciler.access$3(XtextReconciler, XtextResource, IProgressMonitor) line: 316
    XtextReconciler$1.process(XtextResource) line: 273
    XtextReconciler$1.process(Object) line: 1
    XtextReconciler$1(IUnitOfWork$Void<T>).exec(T) line: 36
    XtextDocument$XtextDocumentLocker(AbstractReadWriteAcces<P>).modify(IUnitOfWork<T,P>) line: 81
    XtextDocument$XtextDocumentLocker.modify(IUnitOfWork<T,XtextResource>) line: 201
    XtextDocument.internalModify(IUnitOfWork<T,XtextResource>) line: 98
    XtextReconciler.run(IProgressMonitor) line: 270
    Worker.run() line: 53
```

Comment: What does `ExpressionListImpl` and it's interface `ExpressionList` extend/implement?

Comment: ExpressionListImpl extends AstExpressionImpl implements ExpressionList
    AstExpressionImpl extends MinimalEObjectImpl.Container implements AstExpression
    ExpressionList extends AstExpression
    AstExpression extends EObject

Comment: In that case, I'm stumped. Try to ask the same question on the [Xtext forum](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=thread&frm_id=27). It could be a bug. Btw: +1 for the impressive collection of useful information.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just posted an issue in bugzilla https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=416913

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already a bugifix in the xText bugzilla. It is a patch to [`org.eclipse.parser.impl.PartialParsingHelper`](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=416913#c2). To fix the issue:

1. Get the file from [the patch](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=416913#c2).
2. Put the content in a separate class in your xText project
3. Register this class by overriding `public Class bindIPartialParserHelper()` in your RuntimeModule (a geenrated class in your project, extending org.eclipse.xtext.service.DefaultRuntimeModule)

The problem lies in the reparsing of an already parsed part of your language: the parent container of the old element was not correctly set. The new element was linked with the old element instead with the parent of the old element.

I guess you figured this already out on your own, but this instructions might help the next person having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Xtext team confirmed that is is a bug with 2.4.x versions. See [the related issue](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=416913) for more details and notification about the bugfix.